# Macbook air 2011-mid keyboard keys Q W E R T Y U I O working sporadically

Tags: keyboard

I have an issue where only QWERTYUIO keys are working sporadically or just not working. I have to press them a lot of times to start working and they work for a while and stop again. I have tried reseting PRAM and SMC but with no luck. When I use the Keyboard viewer they keys are not even being registered when I press them.

Kind Regards

Comment: Sounds like a hardware issue.

Comment: Maybe opening up the laptop and cleaning the keyboard from the other side would help. I have no idea what to do now. Don't want to go to AppleStore and drop 200euros just for a simple fix, they would replace the whole keyboard probably

Comment: If you have a can of compressed air, perhaps a squirt or two under the keycaps would help. Sometimes minuscule food crumbs can be pulverized  by hitting the keys rapidly. Is it possible you spilled something on the keyboard? Because the keys are in a straight row, and not a random selection, I still think its a hardware issue. It

Comment: Possibility it's the battery swelling. I'd definitely get it looked at.

Comment: Replaced my battery 4 weeks ago, it said service battery, I thought the issue would stop but it persists.

Comment: Have you verified that an external keyboard works ok?

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem on my MBP13 mid 2012. After 2 months of research and almost spending $600 to replace the top case I found this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kh88cn_rtLo

I remove the top case of the key and gave a good clean and they start working again!!!

I know this reply is for an old post but I might help other having the same issue. If this doesn't work, it might be a hardware fault :/

Answer (score 0):

here after, you'll find a way to remap some keys with the "Fn" key.
It'll give you the opportunity to use your Macbook air while outside.

See : http://wymiwyg.blogspot.fr/2016/09/une-solution-au-probleme-de-clavier.html

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  We're trying to find the best answers and those answers will provide info as to why they're the best. Explain why you think the link you provided will answer the question.  Links can change and become outdated so we prefer the answers to not just be a link.  See [answer] on how to provide a quality answer. - From Review -

Answer (score 0):

I solved this easily - I removed the cover, on the left side (under letter "P") you can see black rubber on the "moving" part (same as on the opposite side, between battery and motherboard, but on the left side it seemed you can push it a little bit into case). I put a coin there and tape (on the rubber) and it works.

It appears this part is moving and when there is no space between the case and this part it stops moving and works. That's also why sometimes keys worked when bending the case. My opinion is that the problem occurred thanks to late replacement of the battery, which bent the case a little bit and left some space which causes the problem.